# Is there a way to select a document that contains a word not followed by a particular word in full text?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

**I have a table named Documents that has Content field full text indexed**

[image: in]

**Now i need to create a query in such a way that the query should return docs that have at least one word "hello" that does not have word "world" following it.**

```
   --sth like
   select content from documents
   where contains(Content,N'hello(not followed by word "world")')
```

**And the result should be**

> 1. "hello"  -- since this does not have world following hello in it"
> 2. "hello friend and hello world"  -- this document has word hello that
>          is not followed by world it it"

Can a full text query be formulated in a way to achieve above results? If so how?? I want to avoid parsing Content manually as much possible as I can.

Answer (score 0):

What you described is a regular expression pattern and unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support it (even the latest 2014 version). Your best bet is to create a CLR function, which uses the RegEx capability of .NET.

The pattern specific to your example would be:

```
hello (?!world)
```

It will match `hello there` and `hello friend and hello world` but not `hello world`

Some resources:

- [Regular Expression Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) look particularly at "negative look ahead"
- [Creating CLR functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876(v=sql.100).aspx)
- [.NET RegEx class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)